# How to sort two-dimensional array by first column as numeric when list of strings? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array that I'm trying to sort by the first column. However, currently every element in the array is a string, and I'd like the first column to be treated as an integer so I can sort numerically (1, 2, 6, 11... instead of 1, 11, 224, 23,...). I'm using the numpy package to generate these arrays using `x = numpy.loadtxt('file.txt', dtype = 'str', delimiter = '\t')` which gives me:

```
array([['140', 'GGC'],
       ['256', 'AGGG'],
       ['841', 'CA'],
       ['46', 'TTATAGG'],
       ['64', 'AGAGAAAGGATTATG'],
       ['156', 'AGC'],
       ['187', 'GGA'],
       ['701', 'TTCG'],
       ['700', 'TC']], 
      dtype='|S15')
```

1) I know I can convert the first column to integers using:

```
x[:,0].astype(int)
```

which outputs a 1-D array. But I'm not sure how to make changes directly to my 2-D array?

2) Once I can convert (or treat) my first column to integers, I know I can sort using:

```
sorted(x, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

But is this the best way to do so for my data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with  `array` data, you can get the sort indices based off the first column using [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and then simply index into the array with those, like so -

```
x[x[:,0].astype(int).argsort()]
```

From performance point of view, this should be much better than with `lambda` as using `argsort` and then `indexing` are all vectorized methods which work very efficiently with array data.

Sample run -

```
In [56]: x
Out[56]: 
array([['140', 'GGC'],
       ['256', 'AGGG'],
       ['841', 'CA'],
       ['46', 'TTATAGG'],
       ['64', 'AGAGAAAGGATTATG'],
       ['156', 'AGC'],
       ['187', 'GGA'],
       ['701', 'TTCG'],
       ['700', 'TC']], 
      dtype='|S15')

In [57]: x[x[:,0].astype(int).argsort()]
Out[57]: 
array([['46', 'TTATAGG'],
       ['64', 'AGAGAAAGGATTATG'],
       ['140', 'GGC'],
       ['156', 'AGC'],
       ['187', 'GGA'],
       ['256', 'AGGG'],
       ['700', 'TC'],
       ['701', 'TTCG'],
       ['841', 'CA']], 
      dtype='|S15')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best way to sort this array list

```
sorted(x, key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the in-built sort functions within `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

dtype = [('id', int), ('seq', '|S15')]
x = np.array([('140', 'GGC'),
              ('256', 'AGGG'),
              ('841', 'CA'),
              ('46', 'TTATAGG'),
              ('64', 'AGAGAAAGGATTATG'),
              ('156', 'AGC'),
              ('187', 'GGA'),
              ('701', 'TTCG'),
              ('700', 'TC')],
             dtype=dtype)

x_copy = np.sort(x, order='id') # quicksort
x_copy = np.sort(x, order='id', kind='mergesort') # stable sort
x.sort(order='id') # in-place quicksort
```

Specify the data type of the columns of your array at initialization so you don't have to create a view later on, then run the sort. You can do this by specifying `dtype=` when you first load the data from the text file:

```
dtype = [('id', int), ('seq', '|S15')]
x = numpy.loadtxt('file.txt', dtype=dtype, delimiter = '\t')
```

`np.sort()` creates a copy of the array, which might be slower with larger datasets. `x.sort()` does it in-place.

You can also specify the algorithm used. Generally, `quicksort` is the fastest, however if you need a stable sort, use `mergesort` - it is the only stable sort offered by `numpy` (i.e. if `[(1, 'GGC'), (1, 'GGA'), ...]` is sorted, the keys with the same value remain in the same order as they were before sorting, GGC before GGA).

Although `quicksort` runs in quadratic time as compared to `mergesort` (which runs in linear-log time), `quicksort` is usually faster in practice.